# Поведение временной переменной при использовании срезов

Tags: python, срез

Нужно просуммировать все элементы списка после переменной (i), использовал срез [i:], но почему-то выводится очень странный результат. Вместо 16 и 17 - выводится просто пустой список [], на третьей итерации - выводится 5-й и 2-й элементы сразу, потом 3,5,2, после чего - вообще "2". В то же время, если сделать все то же самое, но выводить все числа перед i - работает беспрекословно. Сама задача заключается в том, чтобы произвести сравнение между каждый элементов списка и суммой элементов, идущих справа от него.
Мой вариант:

```
new_list = []
numbers: [16,17,4,3,5,2]
for i in numbers:
   if i > sum(numbers[i:]):
       new_list.append(i)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно реализовать логику со срезами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: в срез надо подставлять индекс, а не сам элемент списка. так что ваш код надо сильно переписать, чтоб получить то, что вы хотите получить

Comment: В общем, пришлось действительно отойти от этого варианта решения. Прошёл этот код:

new_list = []
    numbers.append(0)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        for s in numbers[i:]:
            numbers.pop(0)
            if sum(numbers) < s:
                new_list.append(s)
   
    print(new_list)